# Android ListView w/ TextView at top and EditText & Button at bottom

Tags: android, listview

Some day I will crack the code on these Android layouts. *sigh*

I need an activity with a TextView fixed to the top of the screen, a scrollable listview below that, and at the bottom, fixed to the screen, an editText and a button (the idea is for users to be able to add items to the list).

Working code below as question is now answered:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvAddQuizWordQuizName"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:text="Quiz Name" 
         android:textSize="26dip"
         />

     <ListView 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvAddQuizWordQuizName"
         android:layout_above="@+id/bottomArea"
         />

     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:id="@+id/bottomArea"
         >
         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/etAddQuizWord"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAddQuizWord"
             android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
             android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
             android:hint="Enter quiz word..."
             android:textSize="32dip"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:background="#0000ff"
             >
         </EditText>

         <Button
             android:text="Add"
             android:id="@+id/btnAddQuizWord"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="20dip"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
             android:onClick="AddButtonClicked"
             />
     </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, the textview at the lop and the listView are not showing. I am sure it is something very simple, but I am just not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout below should position the element like you want.

```
<RelativeLayout >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ttvAddQuizWordQuizName"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"     
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <!-- contebt here -->
    </RelativeLayout>

     <ListView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_above="@id/InnerRelativeLayout"
         android:layout_below="@id/tvAddQuizWordQuizName" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That definitely helped. Now my TextView at the top is HUGE (takes up like 1/3 of the screen), and the editText & Button at the bottom get covered up by the listView. So it still needs a little tweaking. I updated the XML in the OP to reflect the current state.

Comment: @MrGibbage The first `TextView`'s height is set to `fill_parent`, that is the reason for using so much space(set it to a fixed value or `wrap_content`). Also position the `RelativeLayout` with the `Button` and the `EditText` **before** the `ListView`, the order is important in this case. I edited my layout.

Comment: I had to leave and won't be able to test this for a while. In your solution, what the inner relative layout for?

Comment: @MrGibbage I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. In my answer the `RelativeLayout`  with the id `InnerRelativeLayout` is the `RelativeLayout` from your question which contains the `EditText` and the `Button`, if this is what you're asking.

Comment: I edited my op with my current code. As you can see, there aren't any controls in the inner relative layout. I still cannot make any changes because I am away from my computer (Disney on ice).

Comment: @MrGibbage I've seen it now, you don't mention anything about that lonely `RelativeLayout` in your question(what is its purpose, where do you want it placed(from what I've seen you're aligning it to the bottom below/above the `EditText` and the `Button`?)). Edit the question and provide the full details of the layout if you want a proper answer..

Comment: thanks for the help. I was able to re-read your answers and got it working. Marked as "Answered".